# Getting "403 Forbidden xxx.myshopify.Com" When Creating A Webhook With The Topic "Orders/Create"

Tags: node.js, shopify, webhooks, shopify-api-node

I'm creating a mini-app to track revenue for merchants. In the progress of building my app. I got an issue about getting "403 Forbidden xxx.myshopify.com" when I create a webhook with the topic "orders/create".

This is my code snapshot:
[image]
More information surrounding ShopifyAuth:

Scopes: read_orders
Shopify API Versions: 2022-01
The accessToken and session are still valid (because I still login the app normally)

Comment: This code snippet is missing lots of information. Can you post **full code** and not a screenshot of the piece of it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @TwistedOwl . I have a solution go to App set up -> **Protected customer data access** -> Request access -> Select your reasons for using protected customer data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking my code, it's fine. The reason is I haven't selected my reasons for using protected customer data.

Solution: Go to **App set up** -> **Protected customer data access** -> **Request access** -> **Select your reasons for using protected customer data**.